# Issue with Android Studio UI

Tags: android

I have had this weird problem with android studio, The UI seems to ghost randomly and will disappear when I click somewhere in the software.

I have searched around and can't find anything that seems related, I have wasted hours trying to figure out whats causing this, anyone got any idea?

It looks similar to when a system lag's really bad and UI messes up, but this is definitely not the issue.

Its android studio 1.4 on Windows 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Image Below:

[Android Studio 1.4 UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irzWk.png)

Comment: when this happens I restart studio. It resolves itself

Comment: Restarting doesn't help but a reboot does, but it soon starts happening again. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Delete android studio, including the user settings, and reinstall it again. That worked for me very well for me.